# How to transform a Python dataframe to a different format?

Tags: python, dataframe, transform, dataformat

I just need help to transform a `python` dataframe to a different format.

My input file:

```
country     1990    1991    1992
Cambodia    65.4    65.7    66.2
Cameroon    63.9    63.7    64.7
Canada      98.6    99.6    99.6
Cape Verde  77.7    77      76.6
```

My intended output file:

```
Year    country     values
1990    Cambodia    65.4
1990    Cameroon    63.9
1990    Canada      98.6
1990    Cape Verde  77.7
1991    Cambodia    65.7
1991    Cameroon    63.7
1991    Canada      99.6
1991    Cape Verde  77
1992    Cambodia    66.2
1992    Cameroon    64.7
1992    Canada      99.6
1992    Cape Verde  76.6
```

After transformation, I want to add additional columns and perform update and then save it to a `csv` file. Not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s hard to read your tables without proper formatting, but have you tried using the transpose function?

It’s like “df.T”

Edit:

Okay I see.  What you need to do is melt and pivot your DataFrame.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html

Edit 2:

Try `pd.melt(df,var_name=“Year”)`

Edit 3:

To merge two dataframes, try 
`pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["Year","Country"])` where df2 contains the year, country, and any other columns you want.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have considered TRANSPOSE but it is not the format that I am looking for.  It is a reformatting of data, not a swap of rows and columns.

Comment: Try pd.melt(df,var_name=“Year”)

Comment: You can see the intended output file has duplicated ‘year’ and ‘country’ but a unique value.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I might try MELT function.

Comment: Hi Jack, I think MELT is what I am looking for. There is another question, if I want to merge with another file with the same “year” and “country”, how do I go about it matching Dataframe and then add a new column (or multiple columns) from other files? In short, I want to MELT and then MERGE with dataframes from other files, of course, with additional columns.

Comment: Great.  Updated answer for your latest question

Comment: Hi Jack, I failed to TRANSPOSE and MELT on another dataset. The intended output is the same as above. Here is my input file. Could you help please?                                                                                     
country         1990    1991    1992    1993    
Cambodia        65.4    65.7    66.2    66.7    
Cameroon        63.9    63.7    64.7    65.6    
Canada          98.6    99.6    99.6    99.8    
Cape Verde      77.7    77      76.6    89

Comment: Hi Tony.  Happy to help!  Can you ask a new question on StackOverflow and post the table and the error message?  It's hard to read the table in a comment, and it sounds like this might be a separate issue.

Comment: Hi Jack, Yes, I have.  The heading is "Unable to Melt a Dataframe after df.Transpose in Python".The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076653/unable-to-melt-a-dataframe-after-df-transpose-in-python

Comment: So far, there is no reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196593/discussion-between-tony-and-jack).